# How to find and resolve CD (Circular Dependencies) in NX, React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, monorepo, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I've been working on a Monorepo and **apps** folder containing 3 projects:

- *admin*
- *commerce*
- *vendor*

Beside **apps** folder, there is **libs** folder which contains separate folders such as *components* and etc.

I read about *Circular Dependencies* and I prefer to check the project out by the way but I don't know how to do this in NX, React.

There were some articles on the internet about npm package called `madge`, I installed it and used but didn't work with NX, React.

Is there any proper way to do so?

Appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into `madge` and it seems you're looking for a visual representation for circular dependencies? NX comes with a built-in visual graph that shows you all the apps, libraries and dependencies that exist between them.

You can run it from the root of the monorepo project in the terminal using:

```
nx graph
```

You can even hover your mouse over the dependency arrows to get an idea of which files depend on which libraries.

More on [Nx Graph here](https://nx.dev/core-features/explore-graph). Let me know if you're looking for a different solution.